telethon's function send_read_acknowledge can't mark megagroup's messages as readed
I got this function in python
I tried to return message entities, but they are similar for megagroup and channel, this function see megagroup's entities, messages and other
@client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True))
async def mark_archived_dialogs_as_read(event):
    async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs(archived=True):
        if event.message.message == dialog.message.message:
            await client.send_read_acknowledge(entity=await client.get_input_entity(dialog),
                                               max_id=event.message.id,
                                               clear_mentions=True,
                                               clear_reactions=True,
                                               )

